# How can you disable result output for the mysql EXECUTE command in workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, prepared-statement, database-cursor

I'm trying to use a prepared statement in mysql workbench in a cursor. The cursor works on a very big data set so it is executed many times. Every time a new result is shown for the EXECUTE step. This results eventually in mysql workbench crashing because of too many open result windows.

In the cursor I do something like this:

```
PREPARE stmt2 FROM @eveningQuery;
EXECUTE stmt2; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt2;
```

Normally I use stuff like

```
set aVar = (EXECUTE stmt2);
```

to silence the query but EXECUTE doesn't work like that.

Does anybody know how you can disable the output for the EXECUTE command in mysql?

Note: I understand how i can retrieve the data in a variable, however what I want to prevent is that it is displayed in the results overview like this [image]

This will make mysql-workbench crash when looped too much.

*edit* because it was asked an example of the @eveningQuery.

> SET @eveningQuery = CONCAT('select @resultNm := exists (select  idSplitBill  from tb_SplitDay where idSplitBill =', idSplitBillVar, ' and ', @columnNameEv ,' = 1 and softdelete = 0)');

idSplitBillVar = the id coming from the cursor. 
@columnNameEv = a column that i am filling in variably.

I added this info because it was asked, however it doesn't really matter in my opinion because the question still stands even with the most simple query. When you execute a prepared statement, you will get a output result. I just want to disable this behaviour.

Comment: Just nitpicking, but did you mean "stored procedure" rather than "cursor"?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It is a cursor defined in a stored procedure, but I don't think that changes the issue very much.

Comment: Can you show example of @eveningQuery quaery?

Comment: I added an example of the query however it doesn't matter much as it happens with a simple select too

Comment: It does matter. The query may create result-set, and you may try to avoid it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The query you use creates new result-set, and GUI client show it (...many times) -

```
SELECT @resultNm:=EXISTS(
  SELECT idSplitBill FROM tb_SplitDay
  WHERE idSplitBill =', idSplitBillVar, ' AND ', @columnNameEv ,' = 1 AND softdelete = 0
)
```

You can rewrite this query, and result-set won't be created -

```
SELECT EXISTS(
  SELECT idSplitBill FROM tb_SplitDay
  WHERE idSplitBill =', idSplitBillVar, ' AND ', @columnNameEv ,' = 1 AND softdelete = 0
)
INTO @resultNm
```

Comment: Ok, that seems to do the trick, I thought the syntax of my query was specific to a prepared statement, but as you suggested, it is not. Thanks for the answer, it will make my life easier. (Ps I will award the bounty asap.)